# rails sending authenticity_token as value for hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is being processed by rails:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PAnRnszu+2txBKn9GtixnTh9yKDZJEZzGBztourguuQUqW702In9CtE9Mgg5k5bkn+/rI5OXH/M6a+8X7qK0DA==", 
"photo"=>{"richiestum_id"=>"IW4Eo+EVsS1Pjq5CGPhmsbB2YoxPfZPYuPAnG4gaWbAJzrvJ9XK3TO+3Nbc7s0HIF+RBDwXOyliahyWujFhXWA==", [...]
```

when the html input tag is properly generated:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/photos?locale=it" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
<input value="3" type="hidden" name="photo[richiestum_id]" id="photo_richiestum_id" />
```

from the rails code

```
<%= form_with model: @foto do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :richiestum_id, value: @richiestum.id %>`
```

The `richiestum` class `accepts_nested_attributes :fotos`

Why is this occuring & how can it be avoided?

Comment: What do you mean by "a nested form"? Nested form elements are not permitted in HTML.

Comment: @richiestum is being rendered and class `richiestum` accepts_nested_attributes_for :fotos

Comment: That does not answer my question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My apologies that my wording was mistaken: the form is not nested within another form.  Question amended.

Comment: If you want to use nested attribute to create multiple fotos at once in the first place you want to use `<%= form_for(@richiestum) %>` with `f.fields_for(:fotos)`. Otherwise if you are creating them one by like in this example use a nested route instead and pass an array `<%= form_for([@richiestum, @foto]) %>`. Passing ids in hidden inputs is itself sort of an anti-pattern.